# Equal-looking Python data frames aren't equal

Tags: python, dataframe

I am following an online Python course, which is getting into data frames.

I downloaded [this CSV file](http://assets.datacamp.com/production/repositories/287/datasets/b60fb5bdbeb4e4ab0545c485d351e6ff5428a155/brics.csv) and imported it into a data frame:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
os.chdir('C:/cygwin64/home/User.Name/path/to/brics.csv')
pd.read_csv( os.getcwd() + '/brics.csv' )
myBrics = pd.read_csv( 'brics.csv' )
myBrics

      Unnamed: 0       country    capital    area  population
    0         BR        Brazil   Brasilia   8.516      200.40
    1         RU        Russia     Moscow  17.100      143.50
    2         IN         India  New Delhi   3.286     1252.00
    3         CH         China    Beijing   9.597     1357.00
    4         SA  South Africa   Pretoria   1.221       52.98
```

I then used the code given in the course presentation to create the same data frame

```
dict = {
   "country":["Brazil", "Russia", "India", "China", "South Africa"],
   "capital":["Brasilia", "Moscow", "New Delhi", "Beijing", "Pretoria"],
   "area":[8.516, 17.10, 3.286, 9.597, 1.221],
   "population":[200.4, 143.5, 1252, 1357, 52.98] }
brics = pd.DataFrame(dict)
brics

            country    capital    area  population
    0        Brazil   Brasilia   8.516      200.40
    1        Russia     Moscow  17.100      143.50
    2         India  New Delhi   3.286     1252.00
    3         China    Beijing   9.597     1357.00
    4  South Africa   Pretoria   1.221       52.98
```

They appear to be identical except that for the first column in `myBrics`.  Some web searching showed that I can get rid of column 1:

```
myBrics.drop( myBrics.columns[[0]] , axis=1 )

            country    capital    area  population
    0        Brazil   Brasilia   8.516      200.40
    1        Russia     Moscow  17.100      143.50
    2         India  New Delhi   3.286     1252.00
    3         China    Beijing   9.597     1357.00
    4  South Africa   Pretoria   1.221       52.98
```

However, the identical looking data frames are still not equal:

```
myBrics.drop( myBrics.columns[[0]] , axis=1 ).equals( brics )

    False
```

Can anyone please explain what is going on?  Thanks.

I am using Python 3.7 from Spyder, installed (by someone with administrator rights) via Anaconda.  The OS is Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: You can use `from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal`, then `assert_frame_equal(myBrics, brics)` to get more information about what isn't the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're relying on equality of floating point values returning true; there's many resources out there to explain why that doesn't work as expected.

I'd recommend importing numpy and using the isclose function on the floating point number columns

add this to your imports

```
import numpy as np
```

and then use the following:

```
eq = np.isclose(myBrics['area'], brics['area'])
```

if you want to go more into the details around what is going on with floats, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's the dtype of your columns. As the docs mention:

> The column headers do not need to have the same type, but the elements within the columns must be the same dtype.

You can use:

```
dataframe.dtypes
```

To see what datatype each column is

Answer (score 1):

Allan Elder's answer is correct. I ran this code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
myBrics = pd.read_csv( 'brics.csv' )
dict = {
     "country":["Brazil", "Russia", "India", "China", "South Africa"],
     "capital":["Brasilia", "Moscow", "New Delhi", "Beijing", "Pretoria"],
     "area":[8.516, 17.10, 3.286, 9.597, 1.221],
     "population":[200.4, 143.5, 1252, 1357, 52.98] }
brics = pd.DataFrame(dict)
myBrics = myBrics.drop( myBrics.columns[[0]] , axis=1 )
print (myBrics['area'].equals(brics['area']))
```

The result was

```
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Quantization error is responsible for the discrepancy.  Here is the series of troubleshooting steps suggetsed by respondents:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
os.chdir('C:/cygwin64/home/User.Name/path/to/brics.csv')
pd.read_csv( os.getcwd() + '/brics.csv' )
myBrics = pd.read_csv( 'brics.csv' )
myBrics

     Unnamed: 0       country    capital    area  population
   0         BR        Brazil   Brasilia   8.516      200.40
   1         RU        Russia     Moscow  17.100      143.50
   2         IN         India  New Delhi   3.286     1252.00
   3         CH         China    Beijing   9.597     1357.00
   4         SA  South Africa   Pretoria   1.221       52.98

dict = {
 "country":["Brazil", "Russia", "India", "China", "South Africa"],
 "capital":["Brasilia", "Moscow", "New Delhi", "Beijing", "Pretoria"],
 "area":[8.516, 17.10, 3.286, 9.597, 1.221],
 "population":[200.4, 143.5, 1252, 1357, 52.98] }
brics = pd.DataFrame(dict)
brics
           country    capital    area  population
   0        Brazil   Brasilia   8.516      200.40
   1        Russia     Moscow  17.100      143.50
   2         India  New Delhi   3.286     1252.00
   3         China    Beijing   9.597     1357.00
   4  South Africa   Pretoria   1.221       52.98
```

**alex067** suggested hecking data types, which shows they are the same:

```
brics.dtypes

   Out[14]:
   country        object
   capital        object
   area          float64
   population    float64
   dtype: object

myBrics.dtypes

   Out[15]:
   Unnamed: 0     object
   country        object
   capital        object
   area          float64
   population    float64
   dtype: object
```

**HS-nebula** suggested using `assert_frame_equal` to see where the differences lie:

```
from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal
assert_frame_equal(myBrics.drop( myBrics.columns[[0]] , axis=1 ), brics)
    # Reports no differences
```

**Josh** and **Allan Elder** said that the difference was due to quantization error:

```
import numpy as np
np.isclose(myBrics['area'], brics['area'])

   array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True])

brics['area'] - myBrics['area']

   0    0.000000e+00
   1    0.000000e+00
   2    0.000000e+00
   3   -1.776357e-15
   4    2.220446e-16
   Name: area, dtype: float64
```

This means that `pd.read_csv` quantizes the text representation of numerical data differently than the combination of `dict` and `pd.DataFrame`.  Likely, `dict` is responsible for the quantization.  I find this inconsistency to be somewhat disturbing, but c'est la vie.

Thank you all!